# How can I make it add a role to someone who reacted the message with specified emoji

Tags: discord.js

As I showed before, this code is supposed to give an role to whoever reacts with the specified emoji, my trouble now, is to make the `Reaction Collector` to undestand who reacted and give him the role. I was looking at the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors), tried the solutions they give, but the first doesn't do what I needed, and the second don't bring the user, and I don't know how to fix it.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'cargo',
    description: 'Give a role to an user by reaction',
    execute(message, args) {
        function getRoleFromMention(mention) {
            if (!mention)
                console.log('No role was passed');

            if (mention.startsWith('<@&') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
                mention = mention.slice(3, -1);
                return message.guild.roles.cache.get(mention);
            }
        }

        const messageId = args.slice(0, 1);
        const roleEmoji = args.slice(1, 2);
        const roleMention = args.slice(2, 3);
        const roleToGive = getRoleFromMention(`${roleMention}`);

        //Bot will react the specified message with the given emoji
        console.log('\x1b[35m%s\x1b[0m', 'messageId:', messageId, 'roleEmoji:', roleEmoji, 'roleMention', roleMention); // show each argument on terminal
        message.channel.messages.fetch(`${messageId}`).then(msg => msg.react(`${roleEmoji}`));

        //Reaction Collector filter
        const filter = (reaction, user) => { return reaction.emoji.name === `${roleEmoji}` /*&& user.id === message.author.id*/; };

        //Reaction Collector
        message.channel.messages.fetch(`${messageId}`)
            .then(msg => msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 4, time: 20000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => console.log(collected.size))
                .catch(collected => {
                    console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 reacted.`);
                }));
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: Currently using v12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Message.createReactionCollector()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.2.0/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) to collect the messages, and then get the member that reacted by comparing the ID of the user that reacted with member IDs.

```js
//Reaction Collector
message.channel.messages.fetch(`${messageId}`)
    .then(msg => {
        const collector = msg.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => !user.bot);

        const reactions = {
            '': 'arole',
            '': 'anotherrole'
        };

        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            if (!reaction.emoji.name in reactions) return;

            const role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === reactions[reaction.emoji.name]);
            const member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);

            member.roles.add(role);
        });
    });
```

Comment: `TypeError: reaction.message.guild.members.find is not a function`  and crashes, I tried to switch to `fetch` and `TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` at `member.roles.add('arole')`

Comment: @SrAranha Oops, forgot `cache`. I have edited it now.

Comment: Did the changes, but now it sends this `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.`, i've tried with the role id and the role name, same error twice

Comment: @SrAranha Try using the role name now.

Comment: Worked fine, I only changed `member.roles.add(reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'arole'));` to use the role mentioned when command is called, and continue working. Thanks a lot, I was trying to fix it the whole week.

Comment: @SrAranha I have updated the code to use a much more compact design if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Look the others topics and you will have all you need. https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-add-a-role-to-a-guild-member

Comment: Ok but, how do I catch which member reacted?

Comment: Look at the discord.js documentation : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-collect and see that there are two parameters in the reaction collector's event.

Comment: @ations Just want to mention that the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.2.0/class/User) object that's returned is different to a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.2.0/class/GuildMember) object, so you have to match the ID of the two objects if you want to get the member that the returned user object is for.

Comment: Just use the function `<Guild>.member(User)`.